# Регуляркой вытянуть значение с этой строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Добрый день, помогите достать значение **Z5Cfc1ABndI** из этой строки регуляркой пожалуйста. Всё никак не могу вникнуть в них :(

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/**Z5Cfc1ABndI**

Comment: По-моему, дольше придумывать регулярку, чем написать:

`var splittedUrl = url.split('/');`
`return splittedUrl[splittedUrl.length - 1];`

Comment: Спасибо, такой вариант тоже супер)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~^.*/([^/]+)$~`

Но split тож хорош, не факт что регулярка быстрее будет или в чем-то лучше.

ЗЫ: Я бы сделал `return url.split('/').pop();`

Comment: и вам спасибо!)

Comment: обновил еще, дабы не плодить переменные) не за что)

Comment: Да, решение с `pop()` круче :)